# mongoDB: Connecting mongod to a remote database

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to work on a mongoDB detabase at a remote location.

I already know that I can connect with mongo via:

```
./mongo bind_ip:27017
```

It works and the connection is accepted. But I want to write to the database at the bind_ip via pymongo, so I need to specify a remote dbpath to mongod (Something along the lines of ip:port:location-on-remote-host), but I haven't found a way to do that correctly. Is this even possible? Could you please help?

Edit: The remote file system is lustreFS and the reason I'm asking this question is because the remote mongod can't acquire the lock on mongod.lock, so I'm trying to start the local mongod and pass it the remote dbpath.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can perform CRUD using python -

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('bind_ip', 27017)
db = client['your_database']
collection = db['your_collection']
doc = { 'name' : 'John' , 'age' : 23 }
collection.insert(doc)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that and it doesn't work. The local mongod just sees no incoming connection from pymongo and the pymongo app just gives 'connection refused'.

Comment: If that's the case then you need to check the mongodb configuration on the remote host. On remote host, mongodb config file should have your ip in the bind_ip parameter. Mongodb will allow requests only from the  bind_ip ips if provided. So if bind_ip is set then it has to have your ip, if bind_ip is not set then mongodb will allow connections from everywhere. Looks like the parameter is set and your ip in not there.

Comment: Already did that. Wrote a .conf file with bind_ip and port specified and started mongod with --config and gave the path to the file. It still doesn't work.

Comment: you did this for the remote mongod ?

Comment: I tried, but the remote mongod can't get a lock on mongod.lock so it doesn't start, which is why I thought I'd use the local mongod with dbpath to the remote location. I also forgot to mention that the remote file system is lustreFS. I'm sorry for that.